# Path of a particle acted by a force always perpendicular to velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

What is the path of a particle if it is continuously acted upon by a force perpendicular to its velocity (given that acceleration magnitude is never equal to $v^2/r$)? Is it still a circle?

Comment: Why do you think the acceleration $a$ might not be $v^2 /r$? $r$ is the instantaneous turn radius and is only constant (a circle) if $a$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a circle if the magnitude of the force is constant and remains directed in the same plane.

If the force and velocity are perpendicular then the rate of doing work, $\vec{F}\cdot \vec{v} = 0$. That means the speed and kinetic energy of the body cannot change.

Instead, it is just the velocity that changes and the acceleration is perpendicular to the velocity at all times.

If the magnitude of the force were to change with time then the motion must adapt to be a circular motion with a different radius (keeping the same speed). Alternatively, the plane in which the force acts could change with time.
In neither case would the trajectory be a circle.

Comment: There are multiple possibilities for "perpendicular".  You could have a constant magnitude force act in different directions at different times and it would not necessarily be a circle (or even remain in a single plane)

Comment: @BowlOfRed yes that is true. I need to arrive at a different form of words.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the path of a particle if it is continuously acted upon by a force perpendicular to it's velocity (given that acceleration magnitude is never equal to v^2/r ) ? Is it still a circle ?

Such a particle can take any continuous path. It will simply traverse that path at a constant speed.

Note that the restriction $F\ne v^2/r$ is not a meaningful restriction. For any non-zero $F$ and $v$ there exists some $r$ which satisfies that equation, so there is no curve where that restriction can be satisfied. I assume what you meant to assert is simply that the magnitude of $F$ is not limited to being constant.

Comment: Sir , is there any specific path the particle follows or can it move randomly?

Comment: There is no specific path. That is what I meant by "such a particle can take any continuous path". That includes random (but still continuous) paths.

Comment: What makes you think it could be 'random'? The path is determined by Newton's Laws; nothing 'random' about that.

Comment: @Gert If the force is random then the path is random, according to Newton's laws. Brownian motion is still random even though it is determined by Newtons laws. Randomness and determinism are different concepts.

Comment: I wasn't referring to determinism at all. Never mind.

Comment: If you weren't referring to determinism then I really don't understand your comment. But I am OK to drop it.